# Need CLI (command line interface) tool to convert PLT file to PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, command-line

We want to convert PLT file to PDF file in the background. Our appplication is java based and we are looking for any tool which we can use in the background which provides command line interface to convert PLT to PDF.

The PLT file extension is a vector-based plotter file developed by Autodesk, Inc. to contain plotting details from a certain CAD or computer-aided design file.

We only want lite weight only PLT to PDF converter tool, We don't want full fledged all file converter.

Any suggetion for any jar, exe or dll will be much appriciated.

Comment: As PLT is just extension, not exact format can you mention the source of those PLT files?

Comment: We want to generate PDF of only PLT file, not its source file or any other parent file.

Comment: PTL can be any format, from text to binary. Please provide the source of these files. If you can add in to the question small part of the begin of such file (few lines will be OK)

Comment: We are generating PLT from AutoCAD. Following is few lines from the begining of the file: %PDF-1.7

4 0 obj
(Identity)
endobj
5 0 obj
(Adobe)
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 21345
/Length1 55220
/Type /Stream
>>
stream

Comment: Please note that its not necessary that plt file will be pdf always it can be any format.

Comment: If the source is autocad you can export it to PDF directly: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-5E91B638-7C4A-4CF3-8F7C-593368D72A97-htm.html

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov for the link, but we want to generate PDF programatically in backend thats why we need CLI tool to convert PLT to PDF.